# creating a notification popup - The type or namespace name 'PopupNotifier' could not be found

Tags: c#

I have the following code that is supposed to trigger a windows popup but I'm not sure how to debug the two errors?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  PopupNotifier popup = new PopupNotifier();
  popup.TitleText = "FoxLearn";
  popup.ContentText = "Thank you for watching this video !";
  popup.Popup();//Show
}
```

> Error :CS0246  The type or namespace name 'PopupNotifier' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

How do I resolve this?

Comment: It looks like PopupNotifier is a [Tulpep project](https://github.com/Tulpep/Notification-Popup-Window/blob/master/Tulpep.NotificationWindow/PopupNotifier.cs). Have you added a `using Tulpep.NotificationWindow;` to the top of the file somewhere? I'm assuming you've installed it via nuget.

Answer (score 2):

This is a third party component, not part of the .NET framework.  You'll have to add the nuget package.

In the Visual Studio package manager, type Install-Package Tulpep.NotificationWindow -Version 1.1.25.

Afterwards, you'll see the assembly in your references.

In the code, if you still see an import, add an import declaration in the class that contains your code to Tulpep.NotificationWindow.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would recommend using a NotifyIcon and the ShowBalloonTip method. These are the common notifications you see on most modern Windows applications. To give you an idea, this occurs on the bottom right corner of your screen with a sound and hangs around for a few seconds and flies off screen unless you dismiss it yourself or interact with it.

You can learn more about it [here on the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160064(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Please add this on the top of your code:

```
using Tulpep.NotificationWindow;
```